# is it possible to get the R survey package's `svyby` function multicore= parameter working on windows?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork, survey

being able to multithread on windows would be awesome, but perhaps this problem is harder than i had thought..  :(

inside of `survey:::svyby.default` there is a a block that's either `lapply` or `mclapply` depending on `multicore=TRUE` and your operating system.  windows users get forced into the `lapply` loop no matter what, and i was wondering if there's any way to go down the `mclapply` path instead..  speeding up the computation.

i don't know too much about the innards of parallel processing, but i did some experiments to see if any of the windows-acceptable alternatives would work.  first i tried overwriting mclapply with

```
mclapply <- 
    function( X , FUN , ... ){ 
        clusterApply( 
            x = X , 
            fun = FUN , 
            cl = makeCluster( detectCores() ) , ... ) 
    }
```

next i used `fixInNamespace( svyby.default , "survey" )` to remove the line
    `if (multicore) parallel:::closeAll()`

but that only got me to the point where

```
> svyby(~api99, ~stype, dclus1, svymean , multicore=TRUE )
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'svymean' not found
```

Comment: [this hack](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2014/07/14/implementing-mclapply-on-windows/) isn't a good solution for the `survey` package because large survey design objects have to be passed to the child processes, eating up any time savings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quoting Dr. Thomas Lumley, author of the R `survey` package in response to my inquiry--

> No. This approach to parallelising relies on forking, which Windows
>   doesn't support.
>
> It would be necessary to rewrite it to use clusterApply(), and I'm
>   pretty sure the communications overhead would eat the speed gain. With
>   forking, the child process gets a copy of the parent process data for
>   free -- it's all done by the virtual<->physical memory translation
>   hardware -- but with the cluster approach R has to send data to the
>   child process explicitly.