# multicore argument in R's survey package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, survey

When attempting to use the `multicore = TRUE` argument in R's `survey` package, I get the following error:

```
Error in glm.control(multicore = TRUE) :
  unused argument (multicore = TRUE)
```

Example code for replication:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)

mtcars %<>%
  mutate(weights = 1) %>%
  mutate(id = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
  mutate(strata = ceiling(row_number()/4))

design <- svydesign(id =~ id, weights =~ weights, strata =~ strata,
                data = mtcars)

model <- svyglm(design = design, mpg ~ drat + wt + qsec,
            multicore=TRUE)
```

`mutlicore` does appear as a possible argument in the documentation for `svyglm`. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737166/is-it-possible-to-get-the-r-survey-packages-svyby-function-multicore-paramet) indicates that this argument may not work on Windows, but I'm running this on a Unix system.

I know the `multicore` package has been deprecated in favor of `parallel`, and the documentation [here](http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/NEWS) suggests that the `survey` package has been updated to reflect this change (see revision 3.29-5), but I'm not sure if or how that may be involved in this issue.

I've also tried installing and loading the obsolete `multicore` with the following code, but this does fix the issue.

```
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/multicore/multicore_0.2.tar.gz"
pkgFile <- "multicore_0.2.tar.gz"
download.file(url, destfile = pkgFile)
install.packages(pkgs = pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)
library(multicore)
```

Comment: hi, look closely at `?svyglm`  ..it allows the `multicore=` option when your design is a `svyrep.design` (replicate-weighted) design class.  it doesn't appear to be implemented for `survey.design` (linearized) designs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multicore= option is only implemented for replicate-weight designs and for svyby(), because they are the only analyses that allow for the sort of coarse-grained parallelism that multicore supports.